Четкое позиционирование текста относительно других объектов / Пустоты в текстовом блоке
Когда-то давно видел уже решение данного вопроса, но сейчас, перегуглив разными формулировками пол интернета, мне так и не удалось найти ответ.
Суть проблемы:
Используя любой шрифт при любых значениях размера, отступов и т.д. мы можем наблюдать на странице в режиме разработчика у текста блок с некой пустой областью, которая мешает быстро выставить условный верхний левый край символа "К" наравне с верхней границей условного прямоугольника (или другого изображения, элемента).
Пример:


body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 30vh;
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <svg svg version="1.1" id="blackrect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
            <rect width="100" height="100"/>
   </svg>
  <p>
    Круто
  </p>
</div>




Как мы видим, слово "Круто" съехало вниз относительно квадрата, так как "физический" блок, занимаемый текстом, больше, чем svg.
Есть какой-то параметр в css, с помощью которого можно уменьшить высоту "физического" блока, никак не воздействуя на отображение текста?
Разбор этой ситуации на хабре:
но там решение проблемы представлено в виде вычислений - это рядом, но есть другое решение, подскажите пожалуйста.

Если я вас правильно понял и вам нужно букву "К" на уровне квадрата слева, то нужно line-height указать нужный.


body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    margin: 30vh;
    display: flex;
}

svg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    line-height: 0.74;
    line-height: 88px;
}
<div class="container">
    <svg svg version="1.1" id="blackrect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
        <rect width="100" height="100"/>
    </svg>
    <p>
        КЁЙуто
    </p>
</div>




Также стоит учитывать, что у каждого шрифта своя собственная высота, в то время как line-height является фиксированной величиной. Поэтому рекомендую вам выбрать шрифт, который поддерживается всеми браузерами. В противном случае существует вероятность, что шрифт не всегда будет соответствовать желаемому уровню квадрата слева.

@user:538809
Спасибо за ответ, но вы просто показали аналогичное решение методу из хабра. Я же хочу добиться результата, при котором "логический" блок, "физический", как бы он правильно не назывался, был нужного размера. Отследить этот блок можно при выделении текста мышкой, вот вам наглядный пример из вашего же :
Выделено "то", и мы видим, что зона выделения выходит за рамки всего и вся.

@P.Y.B.SAVAGE тогда это невозможно, ведь эти отступы созданы под буквы Ё,Й,Щ,у,р и прочие. Просто в слове "Круто", который вы предоставили в виде примера таких букв не было.

@user:538809 Я обязательно поделюсь с вами решением данного вопроса, как только найду ответ. Возможно, вы даже поправите меня, сказав, что я неверно излагал суть вопроса, что тоже немало вероятно.

@P.Y.B.SAVAGE Хорошо, спасибо. Буду ждать)
